# Sorting Logic - Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

All, I am trying to do the following in Excel

Take 2 rows each time say leg 1 and leg 2, check which of the values in column ISO value comes first and populate column Alphabetical order with either 'First' or 'Second'

For eg: for the first 2 rows,110 comes before 150 so the values for alphabetical order will be First and Second.

I want to repeat the same logic for leg 3 and leg 4 and then for leg 1,leg2 and so on.

Any ideas how to achieve this using Excel functions (the table is sorted on leg number)?

```
**Leg Number    ISO Value   Alhpabetical order**
1             110       First
2             150       Second
3             110       First
4             150       Second
1             8         First
2             150       Second
3             8         First
4             150       Second
1             150       Second
2             74        First
3             150       Second
4             74        First 
1             74        First
2             150       Second
3             174       Second
4             150       First
```

Comment: As far as I know excel is limited to how it can do with its own excel function. You might want to write a code that reads the file and recursively loop through and sort it then output it back out. Otherwise here is a helpful link for you:https://www.techrepublic.com/article/master-sorting-basics-in-excel/

Comment: Might be interesting to explain the reasons of 1/2 - 3/4 and continuing with 1/2 - 3/4.

Otherwise, it seems pretty straightforward. As this are couple with `IF` functions, you should do the trick. A first one to test if leg number is `1` or `2`. A second on to test the value with the next row or the previous row respectively. You can repeat that with `3` and `4`and your done.

Comment: @ Siri: I could not get my answer to paste correctly in the "Answer" box, so I will paste it here: IF(ISODD(ROW()),IF(OR(B2=B1,B2<B1),"First","Second"),IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),IF(OR(B2=B3,B2<B3),"First","Second"))). Put this formula in Cell C2 and copy down as needed.

Answer (score 0):

IF(ISODD(ROW()),IF(OR(B2=B1,B2< B1),"First","Second"),IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),IF(OR(B2=B3,B2< B3),"First","Second"))). Put this formula in Cell C2 and copy down as needed.